# Handling notification via setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a notification like Facebook via `setInterval`. The notification is working properly but the problem is the `div` that contains the notification is closing every 6 seconds and i think the cause is the `setInterval`. Is there any way to prevent the `div` from closing? What i mean about closing is, example i click the notification the `div` will pop out and then after 6 seconds the div is disappeared, it's like refreshing the page.

[image]

Here's my script code for the notification,

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     loadnotif();
     setInterval(loadnotif, 6000);

     $("#notificationsss").on("click", $("#notificationLink"), function() {
       $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
       $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");

     });
   });

   function loadnotif() {
     var stud = $("#stud").val();
     var ref = $("#ref").val();
     $.ajax({
       url: 'getrecords.php',
       method: 'POST',
       data: {
         "loadnotif": 1,
         "studno": stud,
         "ref": ref
       },
       success: function(data) {
         $('#notificationsss').html(data);
       }
     });
   }
```

here's the php code.

```
if(isset($_POST['loadnotif'])){
     $ref = $_POST['ref'];
      $stud = $_POST['studno'];

            $sql3 ="SELECT DISTINCT subj_descr FROM subj_enrolled WHERE enroll_ref = '$ref'";
               $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);

              $data = array();
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                       $data[] = $row['subj_descr'];

              }
           $in_str = "'".implode("', '", $data)."'"; 

                $sql ="SELECT * FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN ($in_str)  AND status ='unread' OR stud_no='$stud' AND status ='unread'";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

          $output = '      <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                    <li id="notification_li">
                    <a href="#" id="notificationLink"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>     
                        <span class="notification-counter" style="background-color:red;border-radius:3px;padding: 1px 3px;position:relative;top:-9px;right:9px;font: 8px Verdana;;">'.$count.'</span></a>

                    <div id="notificationContainer">
                    <div id="notificationTitle" style="text-align:center;background-color:#ba4f46;color:#fff;">Notifications</div>
                    <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">';


              $sql1 ="SELECT * FROM notification WHERE subj_descr IN ($in_str) OR stud_no='$stud'";
                $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
                       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
                            $subj = $row['subj_descr'];
                            $des = $row['notif_description'];
                            $date = $row['date'];
                            $no = $row['stud_no'];

                            if($no == 0)
                            {
                              $fac = $row['fac_code'];
                              $sql2 ="SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE fac_code ='$fac'";
                              $resultss = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultss)){

           $output .='       <a href="viewlecture.php?subjdescr='.$subj.'" style="display:block;color:black;background-color:#f6e9e8;" id="notifa">
                          <div>
                            <img src="img/izuku.jpg" style="max-width:50px;max-height:70px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">
                             <p style="display:inline;"><strong>'.ucwords(strtolower($row['fac_fname'])).' '.ucwords(strtolower($row['fac_lname'])).'</strong> '.$des.'<strong><br> '.ucwords(strtolower($subj)).'</strong></p>
                             <p style="font-size:12px;">'.$date.'</p>

                          </div>

                        </a>';
                      }
                    }
                    else{
                              $fac = $row['fac_code'];
                              $sql2 ="SELECT * FROM faculty WHERE fac_code ='$fac'";
                              $resultss = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultss)){

           $output .='       <a href="grades.php" style="display:block;color:black;background-color:#f6e9e8;" id="notifa">
                          <div>
                            <img src="img/izuku.jpg" style="max-width:50px;max-height:70px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">
                             <p style="display:inline;"><strong>'.ucwords(strtolower($row['fac_fname'])).' '.ucwords(strtolower($row['fac_lname'])).'</strong> '.$des.'<strong><br> '.ucwords(strtolower($subj)).'</strong></p>
                             <p style="font-size:12px;">'.$date.'</p>

                          </div>

                        </a>';
                      }
                    }


                  }




       $output .='           </div>
                   <div id="notificationFooter" style="background-color:#ba4f46;"><a href="#" style="color:#fff;">See All</a></div>
                    </div>
                    </li>
            </li>


          </ul>';

          echo $output;

   }
```

Comment: Please add the HTML code as well.

Comment: use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: I always wonder how people understand their code when they have no indentation rules?

Comment: do you want more divs to stack up?

Comment: @Pravat-MujahMaskey I think his trying to do a realtime checking, setTimeout will not be the best as it will only fire once

Comment: The second argument to `on` can be just the selector, not the jQuery object, so `$("#notificationsss").on("click", "#notificationLink", function() {`. Also, it's not clear what you mean by "closing"; there's no code that you're showing here which would cause anything to close.

Comment: Well you replace the html of it every 6 seconds....

Comment: @epascarello then what can i do? is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Only replace the content if you have a message? Append the message instead of replacing the content?

Comment: @epascarello oh the append, but the `data` is the div himself. The message is in that `data` can i append it?

Comment: @nethken - return through ajax content for `"#notificationContainer"` not for `'#notificationsss'`

Comment: @Igor but the #notificationContainer is in that `data` too. Can you check my php code? i edited my question and put the php code.

Comment: @epascarello i tried your suggestion sir. i created another ajax for the notification body and append it to the div i create before and boom it worked! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Always use setTimeout, setInterval will create weird bugs. 
Then put the next setTimeout in the complete callback

```
...
success: function(data) {
     $('#notificationsss').html(data);
},
complete: function() {
    setTimeout(loadnotif, 6000);
}
```